# How to manipulate a python list based on the following restrictions?

Tags: python, data-science

```
    import numpy as np

    m1 = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)

    diagonal = np.diag(m1)

    antdiagonal =[]

    for j in range(0,3):

       x = m1[j][3-1-j]
       antdiagonal.append(x)

    def common_data(list1, list2):
        result = False
         for x in list1:
           for y in list2:
              if x == y:
                result = True
                return result 

    if(common_data(list(diagonal), list(antdiagonal))):

       print("hitter")
  
    else:

       print("Non-hitter")
```

In the above code snippet , the Matrix (m1) will be considered as “hitter” if any integer is repeating in both the principal diagonal and the anti-diagonal of m1. Otherwise should print “non hitter”. The principal diagonal of the above matrix(m1) is {1,5,9} and the principle antidiagonal will be {3,5,7}. and For the given matrix(m1) the output will be “non hitter”.
Please modify the above code to get the result.

i have tried with above code snippet but missing the logic for displaying "hitter" or "non-hitter"

Comment: Are you getting an error message or just a wrong result? If so, please give an example input and your expected output.

Comment: i am not getting any error message. my input is m1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] and output will be "non-hitter" and if  input is m1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,8,9]] then output will be "hitter"

Comment: What's your question? The code you posted runs without error and produces the expected result (hitter).

Comment: for the above code, it displays "hitter" but it should display "non-hitter"

Comment: The number 5 appears in both the diagonal and anti-diagonal arrays. According to your description that should output "hitter".

Answer (score 0):

```
pdiagonal = []
pantidiagonal = []

# for Principal Diagonal
def getPrincipalDiagonal(mat, n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if (i == j):
                pdiagonal.append(mat[i][j])

# for Anti-Diagonal
def getSecondaryDiagonal(mat, n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if ((i + j) == (n - 1)):
                pantidiagonal.append(mat[i][j])

#for "non-hitter" matrix
n = 3
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

#for "hitter" matrix
# n = 4
# a = [[2, 2, 3, 4 ],[5, 6, 7, 8 ],[1, 2, 3, 4 ],[6, 6, 7, 8 ]]

getPrincipalDiagonal(a, n)
getSecondaryDiagonal(a, n)
print("Principal Digonal : ", pdiagonal,"Principal Anti-Diagonal", pantidiagonal)


if len(set(pdiagonal).intersection(pantidiagonal)) > 1:
    print("Result: hitter")
else: 
    print("Result: non-hitter")
```

NOTE: Based on your description, here i have termed a matrix as "hitter" if more than one element will be common, and "non-hitter" otherwise.